# Switching TabbedPage views depending on platform in Xamarin

Tags: android, ios, xaml, xamarin, tabbedpage

Due to design differences in my app pages, I need to show one of the tab pages depending if its running on Android or iOS. I am trying to do like this below but it is not working, it seems to compile but the app crashes immediately. This is what I tried:

```
 <TabbedPage.Children>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="View">
            <On Platform="Android">
                <NavigationPage Title="{x:Static resources:AppResources.StatsTitle}" IconImageSource="stats1.png">
                    <x:Arguments>
                        <views:StatsPageAndroid />
                    </x:Arguments>
                </NavigationPage>
            </On>
            <On Platform="iOS">
                <NavigationPage Title="{x:Static resources:AppResources.StatsTitle}" IconImageSource="stats2.png">
                    <x:Arguments>
                        <views:StatsPageIos />
                    </x:Arguments>
                </NavigationPage>
            </On>
        </OnPlatform>

        . 
        .
        .
    </TabbedPage.Children>
```

What is the way to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **OnPlatform** class is a generic class that must be instantiated with an `x:TypeArguments` attribute that matches the target type

Try to change

```
<OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="View">
```

to

```
 <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Page">
```